# Firefox/Chrome web extension - how do I save outputs that are too big for the console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, console.log, firefox-addon-webextensions

I tried to log the entire source of a webpage with console.log() in a chrome web extension. Unfortunately, the output was too big to save in the console. Even if it wasn't too big, I'd like to save the output in a separate text file so I can view it in the future.

Here's my current code:

```
fetch(newURL)
        .then((resp) => resp.text())
        .then(responseText => { console.log(responseText)}
```

The console crashes/says the output is too big when the program calls `console.log(responseText)`

How can  I save "responseText" to a text file, for easier manipulation, and so the console doesn't crash?

Comment: Have you tried to look at the response in the "Network" tab of the Chrome/Firefox developer tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using Node.js, you can use the `File` object like in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/Arahnoid/9925725

If not, try this:

```
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
download("hello.txt","This is the content of my file :)");
```

Source: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server

Comment: where would the document be saved?

Comment: IIRC, it should prompt your browser to open the Save window.

Comment: Hmm... it didn't save anything, and I didn't receive a prompt. Also, I don't know if I can use the node.js solution because I don't think chrome/firefox extensions support node.js

Comment: Oops, thought of the wrong thing. I updated my answer to add this that you should try: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server. Let me know if it doesn't work!